# MVC 6 .Net Core1 Create Custom tag helper for Likert Scale

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am trying to create a tag helper for MVC 6 using .Net Core RC1.  I have found a few good [sources](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/22/creating-custom-mvc-6-tag-helpers.aspx) but not something super close, [this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/275/custom-taghelpers-in-asp-net-mvc-6) was the closest I found and took elements I thought I needed to create my existing code:

To start with this is my target HTML:

```
<span class="form-control">
                Highly Disagree
                <input type="radio" name="MakingSense" value=1 />
                <input type="radio" name="MakingSense" value=2 />
                <input type="radio" name="MakingSense" value=3 />
                <input type="radio" name="MakingSense" value=4 />
                <input type="radio" name="MakingSense" value=5 />
                Highly Agree
            </span>
```

Right now I am just trying to get one of the input tags to show.  If I can figure that out I will add a loop to get the others.  Here is my TagHelper

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = LikertForAttributeName)]
public class LikertTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string LikertForAttributeName = "likert-for";

    [HtmlAttributeName(LikertForAttributeName)]
    public string ModelField { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var content = new StringBuilder();
        var input = new TagBuilder("input");
        input.MergeAttribute("type", "radio");
        input.MergeAttribute("name", ModelField);
        input.MergeAttribute("value", "1");
        content.AppendLine(input.ToString());
        output.Content.SetContent(content.ToString());
        output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent("<span class=\"form-control\"");
        output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent("</span>");
    }

}
```

Here is my razor cshtml:

```
<input likert-for="CharacterUnderstanding" />
```

However, I only get this as my html output:

```
<input />
```

So it is picking up the tag and processing it but not as I expect.  Help in where I went wrong will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tag helper starting point is an input tag, so `content` starts being a self closing input tag.

The first thing you want to do is turn that into a span tag, for example:

```
//Replace initial output (an input tag) with a span
var outerTag = new TagBuilder("span");
outerTag.AddCssClass("form-control");
output.MergeAttributes(outerTag);
output.TagName = outerTag.TagName;
output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
```

Now since output is a span tag you can start adding the inner contents:

- The *Highly Agree*, *Highly Disagree* labels can be added as pre/post content (still inside the span):

  ```
  //Add Pre/Post texts
  output.PreContent.SetHtmlContent("Highly Disagree");
  output.PostContent.SetHtmlContent("Highly Agree");
  ```
- The radio buttons can be appended to the content of the span:

  ```
  //Add the radio buttons
  for(var x =0; x<5; x++)
  {
      var input = new TagBuilder("input");
      input.MergeAttribute("type", "radio");
      input.MergeAttribute("name", ModelField);
      input.MergeAttribute("value", x.ToString());
      output.Content.Append(input);
  }
  ```

With this tag helper in place, the following line in the razor view:

```
<input likert-for="CharacterUnderstanding" />
```

Is rendered as:

```
<span class="form-control">
    Highly Disagree
    <input name="CharacterUnderstanding" type="radio" value="0">
    <input name="CharacterUnderstanding" type="radio" value="1">
    <input name="CharacterUnderstanding" type="radio" value="2">
    <input name="CharacterUnderstanding" type="radio" value="3">
    <input name="CharacterUnderstanding" type="radio" value="4">
    Highly Agree
</span>
```

As a side note, you want to be careful when adding contents using the overloads that accept strings. In your original code the line `content.AppendLine(input.ToString());` was actually appending *Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.TagBuilder* instead of the tag builder content.

Comment: Thanks for the detail.  I think I see where I went wrong and will pursue when I have a few minutes.  I guess I am not sure what output.MergeAttributes is doing.  Does output have a MergeAttributes?  Should that be input.MergeAttribute(key,value)?

Comment: As an update.  I was able to get most of this working however, I can't seem to get the Span CSS class to add.  So everything renders HTML correctly but no class for span?

Comment: `output.MergeAttributes` uses an extension method in `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers` (assuming RC1). I am using it add the form-control class to the output span, while also allowing additional attributes and classes being specified in the razor code. For example you can have in razor `<input likert-for="CharacterUnderstanding" class="foo" />` which would render as `<span class="foo form-control">...</span>`. Have you tried the code as in the answer? It works fine for me

Comment: Got it was just missing the TagHelpers reference.  Thanks again for the code and the clear explanation.